# ng build --watch : modules[moduleId] is undefined

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm currently trying to test the `ng build --watch` function to edit my Angular views without build it manually any times.

I didn't have any error when launching it, but when I try to access my website I have those errors on the console (different error on Firefox and Chrome)

**Chrome**: 
    `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

**Firefox**: 
    `TypeError: modules[moduleId] is undefined`

After some research the problem is the same, and it's located in a bootstrap file : Here is a piece of code :

```
function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

    // Check if module is in cache
    if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
        return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
    }
    // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
    var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
        i: moduleId,
        l: false,
        exports: {}
    };

    // Execute the module function
    modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

    // Flag the module as loaded
    module.l = true;

    // Return the exports of the module
    return module.exports;
}
```

I'm pretty new to this world, do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong ? (I try to empty the browser cache, without success). If you need more informations about the project, I could give you what you need

EDIT : When I run `ng build --prod`, everything works great.

Comment: Are u able to share it via https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because dynamically inserted scripts are async by default. You have to explicitly disable that with `script.async = false`.

Refer this article: https://swizec.com/blog/arcane-javascript-knowledge-still-useful/swizec/7932